# Accessing a map's key and value with @ngFor in Dart

Tags: dart, angular, angular2-forms

I don't know if its possible but I have been searching and did not see any information relating to accessing the key of the map using *ngFor.

Given:

#### .dart

```
 Map people = [
    { name: 'Anderson', age: 35, city: 'Sao Paulo' },
    { name: 'John', age: 12, city: 'Miami' },
    { name: 'Peter', age: 22, city: 'New York' }
  ];
```

#### .html

```
<table class="ui celled table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>City</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr *ngFor="#p of people">
    <td>{{<!--place the value of the maps key here-->}}</d>
    <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ p.age }}</td>
    <td>{{ p.city }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to place the string value of the key at the position indicated?

Thanks

### EDIT1 - clarification

In dart the for loop can be used as shown below to access the key and value of the map

```
map.forEach((k, v)
 {
   print('key|$k, value|$v');
 });
```

Does the *ngFor offer any such mechanism?

Comment: Do you mean the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<td>{{<!--place the value of the maps key here-->}}</d>
```

use

```
<td>{{p.keys}}</td>
```

Recreating your example Dart loop is more laborious because `p.keys` returns a new iterable for each call. That produces the error message in development mode

> EXCEPTION: Expression 'p.keys in AppElement@3:12' has changed after it was checked.

To work around this I created a pipe to remember the previous keys-iterable

```
import 'package:angular2/core.dart'
    show Component, View, Pipe, PipeTransform;
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

@Component(selector: 'app-element', pipes: const [MapKeysPipe],
template: '''
<h1>app-element</h1>
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let p of people">
  <td><span *ngFor="let k of p | mapKeys">{{'key|' + k + ', value|' + p[k].toString()}}</span></td>
  <td>{{ p['name'] }}</td>
  <td>{{ p['age'] }}</td>
  <td>{{ p['city'] }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
''')
class AppElement {
  List people = [
    {'name': 'Anderson', 'age': 35, 'city': 'Sao Paulo'},
    {'name': 'John', 'age': 12, 'city': 'Miami'},
    {'name': 'Peter', 'age': 22, 'city': 'New York'}
  ];
}

@Pipe(name: 'mapKeys')
class MapKeysPipe extends PipeTransform {
  Iterable prevKeys;
  dynamic transform(Map value, {List args}) {
    if (prevKeys != null &&
        value != null &&
        const UnorderedIterableEquality().equals(prevKeys, value.keys)) {
      return prevKeys;
    }
    prevKeys = value.keys;
    return prevKeys;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: Hey, Günter! It worked fine. I just had to put "args" as an optional argument (on the transform on MapKeysPipe class).

Answer (score 0):

To get the index of the current item in the array you can use `$index`

```
<tr *ngFor="#p of people; #idx = $index">
  <td>{{ idx }}</d>
  <td>{{ p.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ p.age }}</td>
  <td>{{ p.city }}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Still I can't use the index to get the key of an item in the map, which is what I am trying to do. Thanks

Comment: You can't get the key from an index or a value in dart?... pretty crippling limitation there. NgFor only exposes `$index`, `$even`, `$odd` and `$last`. You might need to convert the `Map` into an array or list which includes the keys before running it through `NgFor`.

Comment: You CAN'T get the key from an index or a value using NgFor, You can get the key and value and index using Dart.

Comment: Then you should be able to use the index that angular gives you and then use dart inside the `{{ }}` to get the key, unless that's a javascript only zone and then yes I can see the issue. If this is the case, my recommendation is still from my comment above where you extract what you need into an array of objects, and then you put them into the NgFor